# Let gcc inline AND export a function

Tags: c, static, inline, extern

Given a function that needs to be inlined for performance reasons (because it's called in a loop and I don't want the call overhead). Simplified example:

```
void increment(int *single_value) {
  *single_value++;
}

void increment_values(int *array, size_t length) {
  for(size_t i=0;i<length;i++) {
    increment(&A[i]);
  }
}
```

But I want to unit test the function, for example

```
void test_increment() {
  int value = 5;
  increment(&value);
  assert_equal(value, 6);
}
```

Is it possible to tell the compiler to inline the function **and** to export it, so I can link against my tests? I'm using `gcc`, but methods working for all compilers (`clang`, `icc`, ...) would be preferred.

Comment: what does this mean: "so I can link against my tests"? there should be no problem. please do give a minimal concrete example that exhibits that problem.

Comment: The problem is, that if I want to make absolutely sure, that gcc inlines the function, I have to declare it `static inline`, but then it's not exported.

Comment: It's very well explained (for C99), in the [GCC doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) (if I understood the question correctly).

Comment: @iblue: 3 things wrong with your statement. first, to make sure that gcc inlines a function call, you do not have to make the function `static inline`. second, it's not a good idea to force the compiler in this respect. third, if you do (despite the fact that it's meaningless) make the function `static inline`, then that would still not be a problem for using the function in tests.

Comment: @ysdx I see. So I have to use `extern inline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `inline` is a mere hint that the compiler might at will inline:

> "[ . . . ] An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external
>   definition in another translation unit. An inline definition provides
>   an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use
>   to implement any call to the function in the same translation unit. It
>   is unspecified whether a call to the function uses the inline
>   definition or the external definition."

— ISO 9899:1999(E), the C99 standard, section 6.7.4

In fact, many compilers do that to functions that look like your example automatically when being called with optimization flags. Also, the compiler usually knows better than you do what kind of instruction code it's producing, so it is not necessarily to tell it to inline.

In your situation, I'd just let the compiler decide, and not use inline at all. However, if you choose to use `inline`, you can still use that function in a unit test, so no problem at all.